# Seaborn takes minutes to create heatmap of pixel variance from an array of images

Tags: python, performance, image-processing, seaborn, heatmap

I am using seaborn heatmap to display the pixel variance over an array of images (obtained from a video) but doing so takes over 10 minutes and completely freezes my office PC. I'm looking for a way of obtaining this heatmap without all of these problems.

I've tried removing yticklabels as I saw some suggestions that that might help.

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video2.mp4')
#vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
images = []

while success:
  #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.png" % count, image)     # save frame as png file      
  success, image = vidcap.read()
  if success == True:
      images.append(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
  print('New frame: ', success)
  count += 1

images = np.asarray(images)

aax = sns.heatmap(images.std(axis = 0), yticklabels = False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: note your code is discarding the first frame of the video, is that on purpose?

Comment: It wasn't intentional but it's not a problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume it's not `seaborn` that is taking the time here, it's the fact you're loading all frames of a video into memory.  you'd want to make sure you're not doing that!

basically you want to calculate a "running" or on-line variance, without storing the intermediate values.  there are a few ways of doing this with various tradeoffs, but I'd suggest you check out [Welford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_online_algorithm) and there's even a nice Python implementation at the wikipedia page

you'd basically change your code to do:

```
success, image = vidcap.read()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
state = (1, np.array(image, dtype=float), np.zeros(image.shape))

while True:
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    state = update(state, image)

mu, var0, var1 = finalize(state)

image_sd = np.sqrt(var1)
sns.heatmap(image_sd)
```

where `update` and `finalise` come from the wikipedia page

if it really is `seaborn` that's causing things to be slow, then I'd use `imshow` from matplotlib as it does much less work, e.g:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(image_sd)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I've tried the things you've suggested but they didn't solve the problem. I'm pretty sure it is seaborn: saving all the images to file with the same code doesn't take long.

Comment: how big is your file?  I've just tried with a ~4000 frame 720p file, and getting the variance takes 50 seconds, while seaborn takes 0.5 seconds to display the result

Comment: Sorry my bad!! I was inadvertently running the old file! Your solution works perfectly!!!